# Keras CNN: Incompatible shapes [batch_size*2,1] vs. [batch_size,1] with any batch_size > 1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am Fitting a Siamese CNN with the following structure:

```
def get_siamese_model(input_shape):

    """

        Model architecture

    """

    # Define the tensors for the three input images
    A_input = Input(input_shape)
    B_input = Input(input_shape)
    C_input = Input(input_shape)


    # Convolutional Neural Network
    #Initialzers
    initializer = 'random_uniform'
    initializer0 = 'zeros'

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (10,10), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,
                     kernel_initializer=initializer , kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (7,7), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer ,
                    bias_initializer=initializer0, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer ,
                    bias_initializer=initializer0, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    print("C3 shape: ", model.output_shape)
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    print("P3 shape: ", model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initializer ,
                      bias_initializer=initializer0, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='sigmoid',
                    kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3),
                    kernel_initializer=initializer,
                    bias_initializer=initializer0))        


    # Generate the encodings (feature vectors) for the three images
    encoded_A = model(A_input)
    encoded_B = model(B_input)
    encoded_C = model(C_input)


    #Custom Layer for L1-norm
    L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors: K.sum(K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]), axis=1,keepdims=True))
    L_layerAB = L1_layer([encoded_A, encoded_B])

    L2_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors: K.sum(K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]), axis=1,keepdims=True))
    L_layerAC = L2_layer([encoded_A, encoded_C])


    merge6 = concatenate([L_layerAB, L_layerAC], axis = 0)

    prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(merge6)

    siamese_net = Model(inputs=[A_input,B_input, C_input],outputs= prediction)


    # return the model
    return siamese_net
```

The training data is are triplets of pictures in array form with following dimensions: (128,128,3).
And the target data is a label (0,1).

Then we fit the model:

```
model = siam.get_siamese_model((128,128,3))

model.fit([tripletA,tripletB, tripletC], targets , epochs=2,  verbose=1,
          batch_size  =  1)
```

**This works for batch_size = 1 but anything over batchsize >1 produces the following error:**

```
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-147-8959bad9406a>", line 2, in <module>
    batch_size = 2)

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 196, in fit_loop
    outs = fit_function(ins_batch)

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3727, in _call_
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1551, in _call_
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1591, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)

  File "C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [4,1] vs. [2,1]
     [[node loss_16/dense_47_loss/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul (defined at C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_33258]
```

**Does anybody know where the Problem is with batch_size > 1?**

**EDIT1:**

**We found out that the following lines caused the error**:

```
    L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors: K.sum(K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]), axis=1,keepdims=True))
    L_layerAB = L1_layer([encoded_A, encoded_B])

    L2_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors: K.sum(K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]), axis=1,keepdims=True))
    L_layerAC = L2_layer([encoded_A, encoded_C])
```

Removing these lines and just using sigmoid on encoded A and thus, making the model simpler makes it work for batchsizes >1 .

**But does anybody know how to re-add those customized layers properly?**

Comment: try simply changing this merge6 = Concatenate()([L_layerAB, L_layerAC])

Comment: That made it work… thank you! No idea how we couldnt see such a silly mistake ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioning the solution in this (Answer) section even though it is present in the Comments section, for the benefit of the community.

For the above code, with `batch_size > 1`, it is resulting in error,

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [4,1] vs. [2,1]
     [[node loss_16/dense_47_loss/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul (defined at C:\Users\valan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_33258]
```

Changing the code from

```
merge6 = concatenate([L_layerAB, L_layerAC], axis = 0)
```

to

```
merge6 = Concatenate()([L_layerAB, L_layerAC])
```

has resolved the error.